# Copy the first row from a table to another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have below two tables in SQL Server named `tblGlobalGSTRatesMasterI` and `tblGlobalGSTRatesMasterII`. Now I want to copy the first row from `tblGlobalGSTRatesMasterI` to table `tblGlobalGSTRatesMasterII` - please advise how I can achieve this in SQL Server.

Both the tables have the same structure.

This is the structure of table `tblGlobalGSTRatesMasterI`:

```
CREATE TABLE [master].[tblGlobalGSTRatesMasterI]
(
    [MasterId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HSNSAC] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [UnitofMeasurement] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [GstIGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [GstCGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [GstSGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [GstUTGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [GstCessRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtCircularNumber] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ExmtCircularDate] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ExmtEffectiveDate] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ExmtGstIGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtGstCGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtGstSGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtGstUTGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtGstCessRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [TdsIGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,       
    [TdsCGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [TdsSGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [TdsUTGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [TdsCessRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsCircularNumber] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsCircularDate] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsEffectiveDate] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsIGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsCGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsSGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsUTGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsCessRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,    ------   ****
    [SupplyCategory]  AS (case when [GstIGSTRt]<=(0.05) then 'Essential' when [GstIGSTRt]>=(0.05) AND [GstIGSTRt]<=(0.12) then 'Standard I' when [GstIGSTRt]>=(0.12) AND [GstIGSTRt]<=(0.18) then 'Standard II' else 'Luxury' end) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MasterId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
```

And this is the structure of table `tblGlobalGSTRatesMasterII`:

```
CREATE TABLE [master].[tblGlobalGSTRatesMasterII]
(
    [MasterId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HSNSAC] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [UnitofMeasurement] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [GstIGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [GstCGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [GstSGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [GstUTGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [GstCessRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtCircularNumber] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ExmtCircularDate] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ExmtEffectiveDate] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ExmtGstIGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtGstCGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtGstSGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtGstUTGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtGstCessRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [TdsIGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [TdsCGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [TdsSGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [TdsUTGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [TdsCessRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsCircularNumber] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsCircularDate] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsEffectiveDate] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsIGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsCGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsSGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsUTGSTRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ExmtTdsCessRt] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MasterId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Comment: Take the time to format your question nicely, and use proper spelling and grammar (for instance, say "please" instead of "pls", use a capital "I" when referring to yourself and end sentences with a fullstop/period) and people will be much more inclined to help you out. If you won't take the time to ask a good question, people won't take the time to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this**

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [master].[tblGlobalGSTRatesMasterII] ON

INSERT INTO [master].[tblGlobalGSTRatesMasterII]
(
[MasterId],
    [HSNSAC],
    [Description],
    [UnitofMeasurement],
    [GstIGSTRt],
    [GstCGSTRt],
    [GstSGSTRt],
    [GstUTGSTRt],
    [GstCessRt],
    [ExmtCircularNumber],
    [ExmtCircularDate],
    [ExmtEffectiveDate],
    [ExmtGstIGSTRt],
    [ExmtGstCGSTRt],
    [ExmtGstSGSTRt],
    [ExmtGstUTGSTRt],
    [ExmtGstCessRt],
    [TdsIGSTRt],
    [TdsCGSTRt],
    [TdsSGSTRt],
    [TdsUTGSTRt],
    [TdsCessRt],
    [ExmtTdsCircularNumber],
    [ExmtTdsCircularDate],
    [ExmtTdsEffectiveDate],
    [ExmtTdsIGSTRt],
    [ExmtTdsCGSTRt],
    [ExmtTdsSGSTRt],
    [ExmtTdsUTGSTRt],
    [ExmtTdsCessRt]
)

SELECT TOP 1
    [MasterId],
    [HSNSAC],
    [Description],
    [UnitofMeasurement],
    [GstIGSTRt],
    [GstCGSTRt],
    [GstSGSTRt],
    [GstUTGSTRt],
    [GstCessRt],
    [ExmtCircularNumber],
    [ExmtCircularDate],
    [ExmtEffectiveDate],
    [ExmtGstIGSTRt],
    [ExmtGstCGSTRt],
    [ExmtGstSGSTRt],
    [ExmtGstUTGSTRt],
    [ExmtGstCessRt],
    [TdsIGSTRt],
    [TdsCGSTRt],
    [TdsSGSTRt],
    [TdsUTGSTRt],
    [TdsCessRt],
    [ExmtTdsCircularNumber],
    [ExmtTdsCircularDate],
    [ExmtTdsEffectiveDate],
    [ExmtTdsIGSTRt],
    [ExmtTdsCGSTRt],
    [ExmtTdsSGSTRt],
    [ExmtTdsUTGSTRt],
    [ExmtTdsCessRt]
FROM [master].[tblGlobalGSTRatesMasterI]
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [master].[tblGlobalGSTRatesMasterII] OFF
```